# Deleting records from look up table not working in .NET Core 6

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-6.0

I recently upgraded my project to .NET Core 6 and now removing records from my look up tables is not working. I have a `Risk` object that has a collection of `Users`. Removing users from the risk object no longer works. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

My lookup table is called `RiskItemUser`, and it has two columns, `RiskItemId` and `UserId`.

Code:

```
 var postSavedRisk = _riskService.Queryable().Include(c => c.AssignedTo).Where(w => w.Id == riskitem.Id).FirstOrDefault();
       
 List<User> usersToRemove = postSavedRisk.AssignedTo.Where(c => userNamesToRemove.Contains(c.UserName)).ToList();
          
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var postSavedAssginedTo = db.RiskItemUser
                                .Where(w => w.RiskItemId == riskitem.Id)
                                .ToList();

    foreach (var userToRemove in usersToRemove)
    {
        foreach (var riskAssignedTo in postSavedAssginedTo)
        {
            if(userToRemove.Id == riskAssignedTo.UserId)
                db.RiskItemUser.Remove(riskAssignedTo);

            await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code, as you show it, looks like it should work, although some parts are hidden. Therefore, it's hard to tell how to *make* it work. But there's room for simplification, which should result in working code.

You want to remove users whose names are specified by `userNamesToRemove` from a risk that's specified by `riskitem.Id`. Assuming that there's a navigation property `RiskItemUser.User`, removing these data could be done by essentially one line of code:

```cs
db.RiskItemUser.RemoveRange(
    db.RiskItemUser.Where(ru => ru.RiskItemId == riskitem.Id 
        && userNamesToRemove.Contains(ru.User.Name)));

await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You tagged EFC 6, but as of EFC 7.0, there's support for bulk delete (and update) functions, allowing for single-statement deletion of multiple database records:

```cs
db.RiskItemUser
    .Where(db.RiskItemUser.Where(ru => ru.RiskItemId == riskitem.Id 
        && userNamesToRemove.Contains(ru.User.Name)))
    .ExecuteDelete();
```

This will execute one delete statement, whereas the previous method will execute one statement per row.

Note that this bulk method is like executing raw SQL. There's no communication with EF's change tracker and EF can't coordinate the correct order of statements. I think the general advice should be to not mix these bulk methods with regular `SaveChanges` calls.

Comment: Hi @Gert, For completeness, you might include the EFC 7.0+ [ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#basic-executedelete-examples) (can't find the documentation, just what's new) to make it real one-line one-roundtrip :)

Comment: @Ivan Good idea. These functions aren't "in my system" yet. I'll try to do some testing and append it to my answer--when I have time...

Comment: @Ivan. oh, it was actually easy enough.

Comment: Yeah! The only problem is it's coming too late (how many years if we count classic EF). Something that is provided by extensions from long time ago. Now I guess we'll need another couple of years for getting memory joins, or logical relationships/navigation properties (rather than physical FK only) etc :) Cheers.

Comment: Boy yes. But it's a small team. Let's cut them some slack. Also, I think support for NoSql gives them headaches.